# How to remove \n,unwanted text and need to print the quotes ine by line while scraping data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require("fs");

var url ="https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/h_jackson_brown_jr";



 request(url, function(err, response, html){

 if(!err) {        
  var $ =cheerio.load(html); 
  var allItems = $('.clearfix').parent().children();
  var items = [];

  allItems.each(function(index) {

      var result = $('.clearfix').eq(index).parent().children().text();


      if(result !== ""){

         items.push(result);

   } });


   fs.writeFile("output2.xls",JSON.stringify(items, null, 1),

     )



   console.log(items);


     }

    });
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ '\n\n\n\nRelated Authors\n\n\nMark Twain\n\n\nHenry David Thoreau\n\n\nHelen Keller\n\n\nZig Ziglar\n\n\nFrederick Douglass\n\n\nJoseph Campbell\n\n\nTony Robbins\n\n\nAnais Nin\n\n\n\n\nPopular Topics\n\n\nMotivational Quotes\n\n\nMother\'s Day Quotes\n\n\nLove Quotes\n\n\nLife Quotes\n\n\nInspirational
Quotes\n\n\nPositive Quotes\n\n\nFunny Quotes\n\n\nFriendship Quotes\n\n\n\n\nMore\n\n\nTop 10 H. Jackson Brown, Jr. Quotes\n\n\nFind on Amazon:\n\n\nCite this page\n\n\nLanguage\n\nEspa�ol\n\n\nFran�ais\n\n\nAbout\n\nAbout Us\n\n\nPrivacy\n\n\nTerms\n\n\n\n\n\n\nH. Jackson Brown, Jr. Quotes\n\nAmerican\n-\nAuthor\n\nBorn: 1940\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n',
  '\n\n\n\n\n\n\nRelated Authors\n\n\nMark Twain\n\n\nHenry David Thoreau\n\n\nHelen Keller\n\n\nZig Ziglar\n\n\nFrederick Douglass\n\n\nJoseph Campbell\n\n\nTony Robbins\n\n\nAnais Nin\n\n\n\n\nPopular Topics\n\n\nMotivational Quotes\n\n\nMother\'s Day Quotes\n\n\nLove Quotes\n\n\nLife Quotes\n\n\nInspirational Quotes\n\n\nPositive Quotes\n\n\nFunny Quotes\n\n\nFriendship Quotes\n\n\n\n\nMore\n\n\nTop 10 H. Jackson Brown, Jr. Quotes\n\n\nFind on Amazon:\n\n\nCite this page\n\n\nLanguage\n\nEspa�ol\n\n\nFran�ais\n\n\nAbout\n\nAbout Us\n\n\nPrivacy\n\n\nTerms\n\n\n\n\n\n\nH. Jackson Brown, Jr. Quotes\n\nAmerican\n-\nAuthor\n\nBorn: 1940\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nLove is when the other person\'s happiness is more important than your own.\nH. Jackson Brown, Jr.\n\n\n\nLove,\nImportant,\nOther\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nThe best preparation for tomorrow is doing your best today.\nH. Jackson Brown, Jr.\n\n\n\nInspirational,\nToday,\nDoing\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSometimes the heart sees what is invisible to the eye.\nH. Jackson Brown, Jr.\n\n\n\nLove,\nEye,\nSees\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nRemember that the most valuable antiques are dear old friends.\nH. Jackson Brown, Jr.\n\n\n\nFriendship,\nRemember,\nMost\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nOur character is what we do when we think no one is looking.\nH. Jackson Brown, Jr.\n\n\n\nWisdom,\nCharacter,\nThink\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nLive so that when your children think of fairness, caring, and integrity, they think of you.\nH. Jackson Brown, Jr.\n\n\n\nCaring,\nThink,\nFairness\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nNever forget the three powerful resources you always have available to you: love, prayer, and forgiveness.\nH. Jackson Brown, Jr.\n\n\n\nLove,\nForgiveness,\nAlways\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nRemember that children, marriages, and flower gardens reflect the kind of care they get.\nH. Jackson Brown,Jr.\n\n\n\nGardening,\nRemember,\nReflect\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nNever give up on what you really want to do. The person with big dreams is more powerful than the one with all the facts.\nH. Jackson Brown, Jr.\n\n\n\nMore,\nGive,\nBig\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nRemember that the happiest people are not those getting more, but those giving more.\nH. Jackson Brown,
```

Comment: look into regex replace() function

Comment: This does not retrieve all of the quotes for the author, only the first page of them (approx 26). When you scroll down subsequent quotes are dynamically loaded into the page via ajax. If you want all quotes for the author you will need to make additional requests, i.e. work out how their ajax API works.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply

Comment: How  to store the quotes in one column and author name in one column in the excel sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code block, you can do something like this

```
 if(result !== ""){
    result = result.replace(/[\n]/g, '');
     items.push(result);

 } });
```

Comment: how to remove the author name in the output